# Storing related model references in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I'm implementing a bare-bones history tracking mechanism for my Django app, in which the models I care to track override the `save()` and `delete()` methods. In each method, I create my history objects as necessary:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    # Create the historical model based on what we were given
    h = Historical_MyModel(**{field.attname: getattr(self, field.attname) for field in self._meta.fields})
    # Set some other fields as necessary...
    h.save()
```

Since the code for each `save()` and `delete()` method is similar, I figured a good way to prevent typing the same code is to create an [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) to have the similar code in one place. One thing I'm struggling with, however, is how to handle creating the **Historical_{Model}** instance for each child class (each **Historical_{Model}** is essentially a copy of the original model, with additional info like who made the change, when the change occurred, etc.).

In my base class, the method would look something like this, I think:

```
class HistoryTrackedModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        # Create the historical model based on what we were given
        h = SOME_HISTORICAL_MODEL_INSTANCE(**{field.attname: getattr(self, field.attname) for field in self._meta.fields})

        # Other fields get set ...
        h.save()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

The **SOME_HISTORICAL_MODEL_INSTANCE** bit above is the piece I'm stuck on. How can I get the associated historical model for a specific model I'm tracking? Is there an easy way to store a reference to it in each child class? I'd like to prevent code duplication, and I thought this was the right avenue, but I'm stuck on this one point. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Didn't mean to deny your work, but I use this package that's super easy to track history of django model object changes, please take a look. https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history

Comment: I started to use that package, but my application has some quirks that I can't seem to work around. As such, I figured I'd roll my own simple mechanism. I'm almost there, but for this one roadblock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most straightforward way would be to store the value as a class attribute:

```
class HistoricalFoo(models.Model):
    ...

class Foo(HistoryTrackedModel):
    history_model = HistoricalFoo
    ....

class HistoryTrackedModel(models.Model):
    def save(self):
        ...
        h = self.history_model(...)
```

An alternative would be to generate the historical model names programmatically:

```
class HistoryTrackedModel(models.Model):
    def save(self):
        ...
        history_model = globals()["Historical" + self.__class__.__name__]
        h = history_model(...)
```